# How do I copy the primary keys of documents from one collection and save it in another collection in a similar database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to use $lookup to join two collections in my database. I need to take primary keys("_id") from one collection and add them to another collection as “id2” in order to use lookup. How can I perform this operation?

First Collection whose primary key I want to copy
[image: First Collection whose primary key I want to copy]

Second collection where I want the First collection's primary key copied as "_id2"
[image: Second collection where I want the First collection's primary key copied as "_id2"]

I want to copy the “_id” for first collection to the second collection and save it as “_id2”. And them perform $lookup and get both the collections together with my foreignField being “_id2”.

Comment: Showing some example/desired documents in each collection would help readers understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't you just do a `"$lookup"` on `"email"`?